# Move rows to column in bash

Tags: bash

How can I move the below sample data to columns?

```
"FromPort": 80,
"CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/8",
"CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32",
"CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32",
"CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32",
"FromPort": 443,
"CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0",
"CidrIpv6": "::/0",
```

It should look like the below:

```
"FromPort": 80, "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/8", "CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32", "CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32", "CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32",

"FromPort": 443, "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "CidrIpv6": "::/0",
```

Comment: Kindly do add your tried code as your efforts in your question,  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to do two things:

- Change the newline after a comma to a space
- Add a newline before `"FromPort"` if it's not the first one (because you just removed the newline preceding it).

This seems to do it:

```
$ perl -pe 's/,\R/, /; s/^(?="FromPort)/\n/ if $n++;' test.txt
"FromPort": 80, "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/8", "CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32", "CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32", "CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32",
"FromPort": 443, "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "CidrIpv6": "::/0",
```

You can also do this with the "flip flop" operator, but it's a bit longer. In scalar context, the `..` starts in a false state and only evaluates its left hand side. With just a number, that's really testing the line number (`$. == 2`). Once that becomes true, the `..` stays true until the right hand is true (`eof()`). It's a bit weird if you aren't used to it which is why I did the simple thing before. It bugged me that I didn't mention this, so here it is:

```
$ perl -pe 's/,\R/, /; s/^(?="FromPort)/\n/ if 2 .. eof();' input.txt
"FromPort": 80, "CidrIp": "10.0.0.0/8", "CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32", "CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32", "CidrIp": "XX.XX.XX.XX/32",
"FromPort": 443, "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0", "CidrIpv6": "::/0",
```

If there's something else, you'll need to be more specific in the question.

Answer (score 0):

By bash I assume you mean command line, here is one way using `tr` and `sed`:

```
tr '\n' ' ' <  input.txt | sed 's/ "F/\n"F/'
```